# What does this mean and how is it related to polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm learning about polymorphism from the Head First book and I don't understand what kind of properties or how is it related to polymorphism in these 2 examples? What are the differences between these? Does this mean that the myDog object inherits the Animal's properties instead of the Dog's properites?

```
Dog  myDog = new Dog();
Animal myDog = new Dog();
```

Comment: Does the Head First book not explain this?

Comment: Every `Dog` is-a `Animal`. Not every `Animal` is-a `Dog`. In your second example you still have a `Dog`, but you treat it like you would any `Animal`.

Comment: Every example trying to explain the essence of polymorphism with examples of local variable declarations is bound to fail.

Comment: The `Dog` != `Animal`, it's different.

Answer (score 4):

Both lines are creating a `Dog` object. The second line is simply showing you that you can treat a `Dog` as if it were an `Animal`. You can then go on to write code that deals with animals without knowing whether the animal is actually a `Dog`, a `Cat`, etc.

Really this example does not illustrate polymorphism at all. Polymorphism means that code dealing with animals can behave differently depending on what *kind* of animal it actually is, and the determination of what behavior actually happens can happen at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to polymorphism due to the fact that you can now iterate through different Objects that contain the same DataType.

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Cat cat = new Cat();
```

Two different objects. But, if Dog and Cat both extended Animal, you could do

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
Animal cat = new Cat();
```

Now that they are related by their DataTypes, you can group them together:

```
Animal[] animals = new Animal[2] {
    animals[0] = new Dog();
    animals[1] = new Cat();
}
```

Now, even though dog and cat are two different objects, you can treat them the same using their DataTypes.

(for this example, class Animal must contain pet() method)

```
for(Animal animal : animals) {
    animal.pet();
}
```

You petted the dog and cat.

```
abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void pet();
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void pet() { System.out.println("You pet the cat"); }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void pet() { System.out.println("You pet the dog"); }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal[] animals = { new Dog(), new Cat() };

        for(Animal animal : animals) {
            animal.pet();
        }
    }
}
```

By making the Cat and Dog's DataType 'Animal', you are now treating that specific instance as an Animal, rather than what the class actually is (Dog or Cat). This means you will only have access to methods/variables contained within Animal.

Downside: You don't get to use methods specified only in the Dog class if you do `Animal dog = new Dog()`

Upside: You can manipulate/process different types of Objects that share the same DataType